# Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.io.BufferedInputStream@73035e27 (The system cannot find the file specified)

Tags: java, string, file, exception, inputstream

I have to read an outside file from my `\\resource` file in git. I have to use the resource folder, as I am sharing the project with other people, so our paths for the trainingData file will be different. I wrote:

```
public static String trainingFile = Trainer.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("trainingData.txt").toString();
```

Then the `trainingFile` have to be read, and I wrote:

```
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(trainingFile);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
String strLine;
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   
{
    fileNames.add(strLine);
}
```

When I run this it gives me the error:
`Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.io.BufferedInputStream@73035e27 (The system cannot find the file specified)`
to the "FileInputStream fstream" line.
I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Have you looked at the value of `trainingFile`? If not, do. Why do you think it has that value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `trainingFile` is not inputstream and path to file. You can do as:

```
InputStream trainingFile = Trainer.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("trainingData.txt");

    List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(trainingFile));
    String strLine;
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        fileNames.add(strLine);
        System.out.println(strLine);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Trainer.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("trainingData.txt").toString()` will return you a string something like `java.io.BufferedInputStream@7b1d7fff` which is not the parameter you are supposed to pass to [`FileInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#FileInputStream(java.lang.String)) which expects path name.

You can pass an `InputStream` to [`InputStreamReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader(java.io.InputStream)) simply as:

```
InputStream trainingFile = Trainer.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("trainingData.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(trainingFile));
```